# How to sort out 4 highest values of dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nasted dictionary that contains position and tag with score for every tag. I need to filter out only 4 highest values for every position dict [i][t]. 
if i make

```
for elem in sorted(forward[i].values(), key=float)[0:3]:
```

dictionary looks líke now:

```
 dict = {o[NN:0,56;V:0,44;Adj: 0,35.....],1[NN:0,53;V:0,34;Adj: 0,37.....]...}
```

then I theoretically know the best 4 keys, but i dont know how to know here which tag is that then. To  be able to save them  in new dictionary... 
Do you havean idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample input dictionary with expected output? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53501634/edit) to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @NastjaKryvoscheya, your example doesn't run. We need a **complete** example.

Comment: not the proper dupe. one max isn't 4 maxes.